# Get the index of specific tags using Jquery

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to only index a specific element with in a parent? For example:

```
$('h4').click(function(){

   alert($('div h4').index('h4'));

});

<div>
 <p>do not include in indexing</p>
 <p>do not include in indexing</p>
 <p>do not include in indexing</p>
 <p>do not include in indexing</p>
<h4>Tag I want to include in index</h4>
<h4>Tag I want to include in index</h4>
</div>
```

What I want from this is either an alert of 0 or 1 corresponding to the h4 tag I have clicked.

Is this possible with jquery?

#### Update

Thanks for all the answers, what most of what you guys have offered works, but in working practice it doesn't seem to function. I guess I have issues somewhere else in my page.

Thanks Anyway

Comment: You could select the first and the last via the pseudo classes :last :first

Comment: Thanks for that but nah doesn't suit cause I need a return value for a switch statement

Comment: The code already ignores the `<p>` tags. It's just that you then look for the index of *any* `<h4>` tag, not the clicked one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
$('h4').click(function(){    
   alert($('div h4').index(this));    
});
```

fiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/L84QV/

Comment: Can be also written .index(this) like in the first example on the Index documentation http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: Yeah the fiddle example is fine its just in my actual page with all the other code its giving counting all the other tags as well

Comment: then give an id to div and try like $('#mydiv').find('h4').index(this)

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

> If we use a string as the .index() method's argument, it is interpreted as a jQuery selector string. The first element among the object's matched elements which also matches this selector is located.

So you could do:

```
$('h4').click(function(){    
    var idx = $(this).index('h4');
    alert(idx);
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/xFLG2/)**

Answer (score 1):

With this test HTML:

```
  <div id="main">
      <p>do not include in indexing</p>
      <p>do not include in indexing</p>
      <p>do not include in indexing</p>
      <p>do not include in indexing</p>
      <h4>Tag I want to include in index</h4>
      <h4>Tag I want to include in index</h4>
   </div>     
   <div id="test"></div>
```

...and this JS:

```
$('h4').click(function() {
  var index1 = $(this).index("h4");
  $("#test").append(index1);
});​
```

this appends 0, or 1, to the test div element I added.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8Tfq8/11/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('>'+this.tagName,this.parentNode).index(this)
```

[**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/ZVmaL/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/ZVmaL/)